# Using a wireless keyboard (Microsoft wireless desktop 800) with a different receiver than what it was packaged with

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I bought a wireless desktop plus mouse combo from Microsoft. It has one receiver for both devices. I'm currently using the mouse at home but not the keyboard. I brought the keyboard to work. Is there anyway to modify it to use one of the various other receivers (also Microsoft) that we have at work? Those receivers are not for the same model (desktop 800).

Comment: Model numbers/names?

Comment: model no: 1455, 1454, 1461. Lot No. 1103, WO: 1A590, 2LF-00020

Comment: studiohack ... i notice you always edit my questions. Is my grammar that bad?

Comment: I tried to run a Microsoft Bluetooth keyboard and mouse with the internal Bluetooth receiver of a Thinkpad: no chance. It wouldn't be Microsoft if they were not able to make it proprietary.

Comment: I have found that Microsoft is very specific with their receivers and keyboards and if the model isn't the same the other models receivers wont work